# What does "a.u." mean in the scale of a graph?

Tags: terminology

Please refer to the X-Y labels of image posted here, showing the I-V characteristic of a memristor. What does this abbreviation "a.u." stands for?
Atomic units/arbitrary units?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

"a.u." means arbitrary units.

For example, the horizontal scale could, at least in principle, be volts or millivolts or kilovolts, depending on the particular device.